# TensorFlow: Implementing Networks where all if one layer's feature map is not connected to all of the next layer's feature map

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, image-recognition

I am trying to implement LeNet-5 in tensorflow right now, as described in http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-01a.pdf.

I am having a little bit of trouble defining C3 (7 page last paragraph-8 page first paragraph) since I don't know how to specifically tell the network which feature maps from S2 are connected to which from C3 (i.e. I only know how to connect all the feature maps).

My code is:

```
def LeNet(x):
    # Hyperparameters for initliazitation of weights
    mu = 0
    sigma = 0.1

    #This is the first convolutional layer C1
    #Initialize weights for the first convolutional layer. 6 feature maps connected to
    #one (1) 5x5 neighborhood in the input. 5*5*1*6=150 trainable parameters
    C1_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape = [5,5,1,6],mean = mu, stddev = sigma))
    #Bias for each feature map. 6 parameters, with the weights we have 156 parameters
    C1_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(6))
    #Define the convolution layer with the weights and biases defined.
    C1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x, C1_w, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'VALID') + C1_b
    #LeCun uses a sigmoidal activation function here.

    #This is the sub-sampling layer S2
    #Subsampling (also known as average pooling) with 2x2 receptive fields. 12 parameters.
    S2 = tf.nn.avg_pool(C1, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = 'VALID')
    #The result is passed to a sigmoidal function
    S2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(S2)

    #Another convolutional layer C3.
    #Initlialize weights. 16 feature maps connected connected to 5*5 neighborhoods
    C3_w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape = [5,5,6,16], mean = mu, stddev = sigma)) #This is the line I would want to change.
    C3_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(16))
```

Right know the code is working (of course with the rest of the code attached, just showing the important part), but I am not doing what the paper describes and I would want to follow it more closely. I have 5x5x6x16=2400+16=2416 trainable parameters in C3 and the network is supposed to have 1516 trainable parameters here.

Maybe is it possible to define C3_w as a matrix where some of the values are tf.constants and some are tf.Variables? How one would do that?

**UPDATE #1:**

Okay, I am trying to use the split function as in the examples. I want to do the following:

```
split1, split2 = tf.split(C3_w, [10, 6], axis=1)
```

That is, split in [10, 6] along the first dimension (since my tensor is [5, 5, 6, 16] . But that shows me these error:

```
ValueError: Sum of output sizes must match the size of the original Tensor along the split dimension or the sum of the positive sizes must be less if it contains a -1 for 'split' (op: 'SplitV') with input shapes: [5,5,6,16], [2], [] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <10 6>, input[2] = <1>.
```

**Update #2**

Even if the code in update #1 were working, I think I would not be implementing the procedure described in the paper. I would be taking the "first" 10 connections alongside that dimension and discarding the "next" 6. That is not how is done in the paper (see table I in page 8, a little bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Just split the feature map into multiple variables using `tf.split` as appropriate. Then you have separate variables that feed into the next appropriate layer. Backprop will work perfectly well through an operation like this.

I don't know the details of the paper, but it would work equally well if you were to process the entire feature map with in one track, and feed the split feature maps down other tracks, all of these scenarios will work perfectly well.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split